Horror movie that has creatures sucking blood with tentacle on a ship
I watched this movie when I was a kid. This movie is in the 80s or 90s (most likely 90s). 
All I remember was, there were monsters or creatures with tentacles trying to kill victims by sucking out blood using long tentacles through the victim's mouth, and they can leave eggs in the victims body which transform them later. (Like Aliens, but it's not Aliens). This movie was set on a big ship. 
I remember this part well. In the end, 2 or 3 people, probably protagonists are rescued by a helicopter (night time, raining too I think). After getting on the helicopter one of them, who had been contracted by creature earlier before getting on the helicopter, turned into one.
And that's the end of the movie. 
Please help me out. 

is that movie lady hero oriented ?

I believe so NAVEEN.

is that ship or space shuttle ..... like something ...

It is based on a ship on the ocean. Not space shuttle (not Aliens movie)

u means like some creates ....?

can u remember ... how they will look like size,color..... syntoms.....

Definitely black and size isn't too big. Maybe  around the size of an elephant (I think) but definitely have long tentacle to suck off blood.

Was it American/in English?

What did they monsters look like? Were they humanoid or completely different?

This sounds like it could be Deep Rising

A group of heavily armed hijackers board a luxury ocean liner in the South Pacific Ocean to loot it, only to do battle with a series of large-sized, tentacled, man-eating sea creatures who have taken over the ship first.


It's definitely not Deep Rising. Deep rising came out later than that movie. And look at the description of the movie ending.

Does Proteus from 1995 sound anything like what you're looking for?

Group of heroin smugglers finds shelter on abandoned oil rig after their ship had exploded. Soon they find that the oil rig was just cover for biological experiment. One of the results is Charlie - shape-shifting monster with ability to absorb the memory of its victims. However, even such creatures have their own bad habits.

Looking at google images for the movie, I can see that there are definitely mouth tentacles and egg laying into people's bodies. Also one guy's face shriveling up as he's sucked dry.
